# Display plot in jupyter using rpy2 and ggplot

Tags: r, python-3.x, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to follow the tutorial in [here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/graphics.html#plot) in a jupyter notebook. To do so, I'm running all the code as provided, with the difference that I'm trying to run the robjects as indicated in the rpy2 tutorial. But how do you get the chunk with the plot to work?:

```
ro.r('''
    [remaining code]
    gp = ggplot2.ggplot(mtcars)
    pp = gp + ggplot2.aes_string(x='wt', y='mpg') + ggplot2.geom_point()
    pp.plot()
    ''')
```

This returns nothing. If I do:

```
p=ro.r('''
      ggplot(mtcars)
      ''')
p
```

It returns the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NULLType' object is not iterable

R object with classes: ('gg', 'ggplot') mapped to:
[ListSexpV..., ListSexpV..., SexpEnvir..., ListSexpV..., ..., SexpEnvir..., SexpEnvir..., SexpEnvir..., ListSexpV...]
  data: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector'>
  <rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector object at 0x2b6e6f8e7ec8> [RTYPES.VECSXP]
  layers: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector'>
  <rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector object at 0x2b6e6f8e7a48> [RTYPES.VECSXP]
  scales: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpEnvironment'>
  <rpy2.rinterface.SexpEnvironment object at 0x2b6e6f8e7e08> [RTYPES.ENVSXP]
  mapping: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector'>
  <rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector object at 0x2b6e6f8e7f48> [RTYPES.VECSXP]
  theme: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector'>
  <rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector object at 0x2b6e6f8e7ec8> [RTYPES.VECSXP]
  coordinates: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpEnvironment'>
  <rpy2.rinterface.SexpEnvironment object at 0x2b6e6f8e7e88> [RTYPES.ENVSXP]
  facet: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpEnvironment'>
  <rpy2.rinterface.SexpEnvironment object at 0x2b6e6f8e7f48> [RTYPES.ENVSXP]
  plot_env: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpEnvironment'>
  <rpy2.rinterface.SexpEnvironment object at 0x2b6e6f8e7e08> [RTYPES.ENVSXP]
  labels: <class 'rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector'>
  <rpy2.rinterface.ListSexpVector object at 0x2b6e6f8e7ec8> [RTYPES.VECSXP]
```